# numero de variaveis nao bate com os paramentros mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Bom estou tentando fazer um select "bindado" porem a esta retornando o seguinte erro Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM duelos WHERE status='desafiado' AND desafiado='?'";
    $statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);

    //bind parameters for markers, where (s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob)
    $statement->bind_param('s',$desafiante);
    $statement->execute();

    if($statement->execute()){
        print 'Voce foi desafiado por $desafiante <br> Aceitar o desafio? <br> Sim  -  Nao';
    }else{
        print 'Nada a relatar';
    }
    $statement->close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na sua consulta não existe nenhum placeholder, os valores não devem ser passasdos diretamente e sim trocados por apenas interrogações(`?`) não é necessário usar aspas simples para escapa-las, ao utilizar prepared statements.

Mude:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM d
$statement->bind_param(si, $status ,$iddesafiante);uelos WHERE status='desafiado' AND iddesafiado='$iddesafiante'";
```

Por:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM duelos WHERE status = ? AND iddesafiado = ?";
$statement->bind_param('si', $status ,$iddesafiante);
```

Comment: continua o mesmo erro vou atualizar o codigo o status irei passar manualmente

Comment: @ArsomNolasco desafiado é uma string ou int?

Comment: é uma string alterei o exemplo

Comment: @ArsomNolasco colca entre aspas simples os tipos `si` alterei a resposta

Comment: ainda continua , atualizei o codigo para ver como esta

Comment: @ArsomNolasco não vai aspas nas interrogações e chame o `execute()` apenas um vez.

Comment: deu certo aqui o erro sumiu, porem o retorno no print nao esta aparecendo mais isso e outro caso . o problema da pergunta foi solucionado, se possivel altere a resposta incluido essas informacoes